# Infinite loop "foreach" when clone XML Node, C#

Tags: c#, xml, clone

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml("<offers>" +
        "<offer id = '1'>" +
            "<name>Offer1</name>" +
        "</offer>" +
        "<offer id = '2'>" +
            "<name>Offer2</name>" +
        "</offer>" + 
    "</offers>");

XmlNode offers = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//offers");
XmlNodeList listOffer = xDoc.SelectNodes("//offers/offer");

foreach (XmlNode offer in listOffers)
{
    XmlNode clone = offer.Clone();
    offers.AppendChild(clone);

    Console.WriteLine("Create clone");
}
xDoc.Save("out.yml");
```

In the above example, I get an infinite loop "foreach". But if you put a breakpoint inside the loop and open the variable "listOffers" for tracking, the program ends with the correct result. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

[tracking listOffers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43OHv.png)

If you don't keep track of the variable "listOffers", the size of the list grows indefinitely

Comment: For this error to occur it must mean the offers/offer must be a child of another offers/offers.  Solution is not to add an item to the items parent.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist):

> Changes to the children of the node object that the XmlNodeList
> collection was created from are immediately reflected in the nodes
> returned by the XmlNodeList properties and methods.

See also the warning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes):

> The XmlNodeList object returned by this method will be valid while the
> underlying document remains unchanged. If the underlying document
> changes, unexpected results may be returned (no exception will be
> thrown).

So the newly added nodes will appear in the node list and therfore be processed by the loop later.

To restrict to the nodes that were present before starting the loop, you could create a `List<XmlNode>` from it, e.g using LINQ:

```
foreach (var offer in listOffers.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList())
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating a node-list that you're also appending to. So you're also iterating the newly added items, repeat forever. This is a valid behaviour - while some iterators detect changes to the underlying data and intentionally break, that isn't required.

A quick workaround would be to count the data before you start, and stop after that many elements. Another workaround would be to buffer the new data externally until you've finished iterating, and then append it all at once *after* iterating. The latter has the advantage of protecting against a future change where the node list *does* detect alterations and breaks, although that change seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

As @KlausGütter suggested it is better to use LINQ to XML. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xDoc =  XDocument.Parse(@"<offers>
            <offer id = '1'>
                <name>Offer1</name>
            </offer>
            <offer id = '2'>
                <name>Offer2</name>
            </offer>
            </offers>");

    // List() will preserve the original XML elements
    foreach (var offer in xDoc.Descendants("offer").ToList())
    {
        xDoc.Root.Add(offer);
        Console.WriteLine("Create clone");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(xDoc);
}
```

**Output**

```
<offers>
  <offer id="1">
    <name>Offer1</name>
  </offer>
  <offer id="2">
    <name>Offer2</name>
  </offer>
  <offer id="1">
    <name>Offer1</name>
  </offer>
  <offer id="2">
    <name>Offer2</name>
  </offer>
</offers>
```